# How to add a count of observations for each category on a barplot? Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

i'm making a graph using matplotlib for a categorical variable and i need to put the number of observations for each bar (`categorie`) . Can anybody help me? I only find solutions to put manually, but i need to do the same graph for several variables, so i need some code that alredy count the number of observations for each category on a variable. thank u!!

Here is my code:

```
axis_x =  'Action intended to block/propose policy (block = 1)' 
axis_y = 'Take up'
title = 'neighborhood attract more people'
type = 'bar'
column1 = 'g_scope'
column2 = 'take_up'

database = df
graph_mean_diff_c(column1, column2,  tipo, savename, titulo, eixo_x, eixo_y, database)
```

Comment: You need to add how `graph_mean_diff_c` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

[image]

And here the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

N=11
t = np.linspace(0,0.5*np.pi,N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':10*np.sin(t),'B':10*np.cos(t)} )

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

df['A'].plot(kind='barh',width=0.9, color='b', alpha=0.3) 
for y, x in enumerate(df['A']): 
    plt.annotate(str(x)[0:5], xy=(x-0.01, y), va='center',ha='right', color='b', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)

df['B'].plot(kind='barh',width=0.9, color='r', alpha=0.2) 
for y, x in enumerate(df['B']): 
    plt.annotate(str(x)[0:5], xy=(x-0.01, y), va='center',ha='right', color='r', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)

x_majorLoc = MultipleLocator(0.5); ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_majorLoc)
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.IndexLocator(base=0.0, offset=0.1))
plt.show()
pic_name='psc_annotaed_bars.png'
fig.savefig(pic_name, transparency=True)
```

With vertical bars is different. I have tried it
[here](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/cost-healthcaresystem-usa-switzerland.html)

[image]

Comment: This is one of the most asked questions and there are many answers around already. Now if every new question is answered with only one possible (and possibly not so great) solution, people will at one point have no chance to find the good solutions because they are burried deep. Better mark as duplicate and if you think your solution needs to be added to one of the existing questions, feel free to do so.